# Running az cli commands in Cloud shell fails with UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8e in position 0: invalid start byte

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-cloud-shell

I am trying to run az cli command say for exmaple az --version or az account show

I am getting below error :
File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/encodings/utf_8_sig.py", line 117, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8e in position 0: invalid start byte

It was working till date without any issue. 
if I run python --version , it gives me 3.5.2. So looks like i have python 3.5.2 but the error above coming from python 3.6 files.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to open a new cloud shell, it should work.

My python version is also `3.5.2`.

[image]

[image]

**Update**:

Please try to unmount the old storage file share and mount a new one.

Run `clouddrive unmount` in the cloud shell, you will be prompted to unmount the file share, then login again, it will prompt you to mount a new one, finish it and try again.

[image]

Comment: I restarted the cloud shell - no luck
signed out and signed in back to portal and opened cloud shell again - no luck

Comment: tried unmounting and mounting back clouddrive but still the same issue

Comment: @Suraj Did you create a new storage file share?

Comment: added a screenshot in original question for reference...

No, not new one. just unmounted existing and mounted again. will try with creating new as well

Comment: @Suraj Yes, please try to create a new file share and mount.

Comment: it's working with new file share. wondering what went wrong with my existing.... 
meanwhile i m unblocked so all good. Thanks Joy !

Comment: @Suraj I am not sure, maybe something happened to the old file share, glad it works now.:-)